# Find nth term of series with both addition and multiplication

Tags: sequences-and-series, finance, economics

If I have a series that replicates the effect of saving with compounding interest in an economic environment with combating inflation such as:

$$a_{yr} = a_{yr-1}*I_n+N*I_F^{yr-1}$$

Where $yr$ is the index of the term of the series (years of compounding), and $I_n$ and $I_F^{yr-1}$ are variable integers (representing a constant interest rate and compounded constant inflation rate respectively) , how can I find the value of the $yr$
th term?

Comment: If $yr$ is the index, what is $n$ then?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. Is this a sequence of matrices, with $I_n$ the $n\times n$ identity matrix? Or is $I_n$ just a two-letter symbol for a constant **in**terest rate.

Comment: Hi J.G, it's just a two letter symbol for a constant interest rate.